# Symfony2 UserPassword constraint gets a NULL password

Tags: forms, validation, symfony, constraints

I want just to allow users to change their password in my application. I have built the a form to edit the password but the validation never pass because the password of the current user in the UserPassword constraint is always NULL:

```
<?php

/*
 * This file is part of the Symfony package.
 *
 * (c) Fabien Potencier <fabien@symfony.com>
 *
 * For the full copyright and license information, please view the LICENSE
 * file that was distributed with this source code.
 */

namespace Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Validator\Constraints;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContextInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\EncoderFactoryInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintValidator;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Exception\ConstraintDefinitionException;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Exception\UnexpectedTypeException;

class UserPasswordValidator extends ConstraintValidator
{
    private $securityContext;
    private $encoderFactory;

    public function __construct(SecurityContextInterface $securityContext, EncoderFactoryInterface $encoderFactory)
    {
        $this->securityContext = $securityContext;
        $this->encoderFactory = $encoderFactory;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function validate($password, Constraint $constraint)
    {
        if (!$constraint instanceof UserPassword) {
            throw new UnexpectedTypeException($constraint, __NAMESPACE__.'\UserPassword');
        }

        $user = $this->securityContext->getToken()->getUser();

        if (!$user instanceof UserInterface) {
            throw new ConstraintDefinitionException('The User object must implement the UserInterface interface.');
        }

        $encoder = $this->encoderFactory->getEncoder($user);

        //I tried to print $user->getPassword from here and it is always NULL
        if (!$encoder->isPasswordValid($user->getPassword(), $password, $user->getSalt())) {
            $this->context->addViolation($constraint->message);
        }
    }
}
```

This is fhe form I'm using to change the password:

```
class UserPasswordEditType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('oldPassword', 'password', array(
            'constraints' => array(
                new UserPassword(array(
                        'message' => 'password_current.invalid',
                        'groups' => 'user-password-edit'
                    )
                ),
                new NotBlank(array(
                    'message' => 'not_blank',
                    'groups' => 'user-password-edit'
                ))
            ),
            'mapped' => false,
            'required' => true,
        ))
            ->add('password', 'repeated', array(
                'type' => 'password',
                'invalid_message' => 'password_repeat.invalid',
                'required' => true,
                'first_options' => array('label' => 'password.label'),
                'second_options' => array('label' => 'password_repeat.label'),
            ))
            ->add('save', 'submit', array(
                'label' => 'save.label'
            ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'user_edit_password';
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'validation_groups' => array('user-password-edit'),
        ));
    }
}
```

This is a slice of the security.yml

```
  security:
      encoders: 
          Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext
          XXX\PrivateApplication\Bundle\UserBundle\Entity\User: plaintext

  role_hierarchy:
      ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
      ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

  providers:
      chain_provider:
        chain:
            providers: [in_memory, user_db]
      in_memory:
          memory:
              users:
                  API_DOC:  { password: @aaa, roles: [ 'ROLE_API_DOC' ] }
      user_db:
          entity: { class: XXX\PrivateApplication\Bundle\UserBundle\Entity\User, property: username }
```

Why the password of the logged user is always NULL from the constraint? If I print it from the controller it works... I don't use the FOSUserBundle.

Thank you

PS:
I have found a similar question [Using Symfony2 UserPassword validator in form type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22042998/using-symfony2-userpassword-validator-in-form-type) but without replies...

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I am experiencing the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

> Why the password of the logged user is always NULL from the constraint? If I print it from the controller it works...

The thing is, that in `$password` is your plain password from the form, not in `getPassword()`! You retrieve the 'signed in' user from the token of the security context and the encoded password is NULL. That means, that probably also `getUsername()` is NULL and `getRoles()` is just anonymous or guest (don't know it right now).

Then the login at all doesn't work and the token is only anonymous.

Comment: Nope. In the controller I can print the password using $this->getUser()->getPassword(). And the user is completely logged, I can print the other information (as username, etc.) from the constraint.

Comment: do you use fos_user? maybe you use different security contexts?

Comment: I have updated my question inserting info about the security.yml. No I don't use fos_user.

Comment: please also add the lines from `services.yml` how to create `UserPasswordValidator`

Comment: I can't, this is not a custom validator. The UserPassword validator is included in the Symfony constraints suite: http://symfony.com/en/doc/current/reference/constraints/UserPassword.html